# Spring MVC web application works fine on standalone tomcat but failed when deployed on cloud

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, web-applications, tomcat7, cloud

I am running a maven based spring web application on my local tomcat 7.0 and it works fine but when I run it on cloud, it is failed with the BeanCreationException.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ServiceImpl': In
jection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframewor
k.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:xxx
```

The cloud also runs the webapplications on tomcat7. I am not sure what can be the other causes of error.Any one ever face this issue before? Thanks

Comment: Is there any more to the stack trace?

Comment: How are you providing the spring config? Do you have a main config class? Is this class being run in the same way on both env?

Comment: It seems like a configuration problem. More information is required.